# Must login twice before entering Unity; first login screen has graphical anomalies

Tags: 11.10, login, login-screen, lightdm

When booting my computer I am first presented with the regular lightdm login screen except there are some graphical anomalies in the top 5th of the screen. When I press a key on the keyboard the graphical the anomalies change in a similar fashion to The Matrix code. Probably the best way to explain what this looks like is having a few characters (similar to what you get when you open a binary file in a text editor but in small font) being overlaid on the login screen. When I press more keys it's as if those events are being written into the screen buffer and I'm looking directly at a memory map. This even happens when I press 'shift'.

Once I enter my password the screen flashes and I have another lightdm login screen but this time without the anomalies. On entering my password again I can login to unity and everything seems fine.

I am running the 64-bit version of Oneiric Ocelot with Nvidia 280.13 drivers. It has only started within the last week or so, which corresponds to when I was installing software to allow screen rotation and also a large set of software centre updates (including kernel update).

Comment: you can add this as an answer, so it will help others in the future.

Comment: Thanks but upon reboot it's doing it again. I have removed the comment now as this hasn't been resolved.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Using 11.10 64bit with nVidia drivers.. I have no artefacts or anomalies, however every time the system is started I have to log in twice. However if I log out and log back in it takes my credentials the first time.

Comment: Good, I'm glad I wasn't alone with this. I have since enabled automatic login for the machine exhibiting this problem which has hidden the problem from view.

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/874218) and as such is now closed.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I don't think this is localized and it didn't use to do this...