# Why do I sometimes log in twice (instead of once)?

Tags: 11.10

Often, when I boot up my PC, the Ubuntu 11.10 login screen prompts me to enter my login details (as per normal), but after I've done that, it asks me a second time.

To be clear, I log in the first time. 
The screen goes black.
The login screen appears a second time.
I log in a second time, and it works.

This happens often enough for me to question it.

Comment: Is this behaviour user specific?  Try creating a new user account and log into that.  If it still occurs, then its likely to be a graphical issue - what is your graphics card and what drivers are you using?

Comment: There is only one user on this PC, and it is me. I am running dual Nvidia GTX 460 cards and I've not had any login bugs with other distros. In fact, that I know of, I've had no graphical hassles at all.

I AM, however, running Simple LightDM, so that I can have a consistent desktop wallpaper at login. Not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: give my suggestion a try - you can always delete the user account later.  Which nvidia driver have you installed?

Comment: Will give it a shot.

I am using the driver that was offered to me when I installed 11.10. I had two options; the recommended one and the post-release one. I chose the post-release one, although it seems no different to the recommended one (after trying both).

Comment: I do suffer from the same problem. I blame(ed) my windows partition. not off logic or sound reasoning... but because windows was buggy and p'd me off. I will try to find out more about what is causing the issue and post.

Comment: @Gonzoza - its been a while since your last update to your question.  Please can you edit with the latest findings, what you have investigated etc.  Thanks.

Comment: When it goes black after the first log in, is it fading to black, or just going black instantly?  Are you using gnome-shell or unity?  I have experienced it fading to black with gnome shell if I log in after waking the machine up from suspend...

Comment: @jatoo He said he is using LightDM. More feedbacks from Gonzoza will be nice.

Comment: [Similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74925/must-login-twice-before-entering-unity-first-login-screen-has-graphical-anomali) has been closed, damn moderatrolerrs...

Comment: I think it is independant of loginmanger .I faced the same problem in kdm and gdm too,

but it is due to the configuaration of each user ,Because i have face problem in one of the user only

Comment: I've experienced double logins once or twice (and not much more) since posting this question, but I've not been able to figure out the pattern. It happened, one time, after I booted up.

Comment: try to update your lightdm and lightdm-gtk-greeter package. If it does not work then try with another account (don't delete existing one) that both account face the same problem

Comment: It is possibly related to this bug which has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/874218).??

Comment: Would you mind providing the output of your /etc/passwd file (This command --> sudo vipw <--)?

Comment: It sounds like on some logins X is crashing, which would return you to the login screen. Can you provide the contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log ?

Comment: Check your /var/log/auth.log for messages. `less /var/log/auth.log`. Share highlights of your results in the comments.

Comment: Are you using Gnome 3.4? I have a similar issue, and i also have a Nvidia Card. I tyoe the password, the screen apparently logs in, but the screen darkens again, and asks for the password again, as if i had locked the screen

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue due to some mixup of keyrings.

Go to System / Preferences / Passwords and Encryption Keys.

I had two keyrings there, one called "login" with no keys in it, and another called "default" with several keys, for example the password for my wifi.

1. Copy the passwords of all the keys in the "default" keyring (for backup)
2. Delete the default keyring
3. Logout
4. Login, and re-enter passwords when asked, for example for your wifi, etc

From this point on your keys and passwords will be stored in the "login" keyring. This keyring is unlocked when you login to Ubuntu, so you only have to enter your password once.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing Plymouth and the restart. And please tell if the problem is resolved or not.

You can refer this link which states that if your password contains number "2" then gnome restarts. Also please tell me if you are using gnome along with Ubuntu .

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1417140

Comment: I have updated my post. Please try and revert to it.

Comment: This comment is unhelpful. "Try removing Plymouth" is like advising someone to fix their car but not telling them how to do it.

Comment: You can remove Plymouth from synaptic.

start synaptic package manager > search for Plymouth in quick filter > then click on green button and select "mark for removal" and apply the changes. And its done

Comment: @Gonzoza have you tried removing Plymouth or changed your password so that it does not contain number 2.

Comment: No I haven't. I've not had this problem in weeks, so I see no reason why I need to tinker with it, for now.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happens to one of the user-accoun ,I resolved it via switching login manager

First I installed kdm and set it as default login manager

```
sudo apt-get install kdm 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and chose kdm

Then switch back to lightdm if you hate kdm

Now single login is enough

Answer (score 0):

The key quote from the OP as to whether this is still an issue is:

> No I haven't. I've not had this problem in weeks, so I see no reason
>   why I need to tinker with it, for now.

To diagnose this types of issues first a simple check is to see if a theme or other configuration causes this issue.

Thus the question:

> Is this behaviour user specific? Try creating a new user account and
>   log into that.

If by creating a new user and the issue still occurs then the problem is highly likely to be either a graphical issue and/or a compiz issue.

Both of these issues should be reported as a [bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

It would be helpful in such a report to looks at posting the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.  Often you can see what the issue is by looking for errors in this log.

---

In conclusion - the OP states this has not occurred for weeks.  Its highly likely an update (graphical related or compiz related) has resolved this question.

Case-Closed :)

Comment: It happends to me when i installed vistar theme twise ,it creates a new user to apply changes when i did twise it may created configuration files twise,


similar issue happend in 10.04 when I disabled automatic login twise ,i just reinstalled ubuntu for fixing it